# StreamWriter encoding

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

I am processing some very large files to find and replace strings, so I need to use StreamReader and StreamWriter. And I also need to support multiple encoding. I have

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\ANSI.txt")
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", $reader.CurrentEncoding)
```

It doesn't throw any kind of error, but no matter what the source encoding the output file is always 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding'. Obviously I am missing something basic, but the lack of a thrown error has me stumped.

EDIT: I tried forcing ASCII with the constructor above, like this

```
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding])
```

But still somehow the output is UTF8, but with no errors. Curriouser and curiouser.

EDIT 2: So, based on comments, I tried forcing ASCII, and I added here the code I am using to see what the results file is encoded as. Maybe THAT'S where I have gone wrong?

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\ANSI.txt")
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)

try {
    while (-not ($reader.EndOfStream)) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        $writer.WriteLine($line)
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
    $writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()
}

$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
$writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()

$test = [IO.StreamReader]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt")
Write-Host "$($test.CurrentEncoding)!!!"
$test.Close(); $test.Dispose()
```

And ultimately I need to be able to convert the text expression that I get from .CurrentEncoding into the proper format for the Constructor. Is there some function available for that, or am I going to be making my own table for that conversion?

Hmm, weird. I have a file that I can verify is a UNICODE file via NotePad++, but this still reports UTF8.

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\UNICODE.txt", $true)
Write-Host "$($reader.CurrentEncoding)"
$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
```

And yet, this little function returns Unicode correctly.

```
function Get-PxFileEncoding {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$filePath
    )

    [Byte[]] $byte = get-content -path:$filePath -encoding:Byte -readCount:4 -totalCount:4

    if ($byte[0] -eq 0xef -and $byte[1] -eq 0xbb -and $byte[2] -eq 0xbf) { 
        $encoding = 'UTF8' 
    } elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[1] -eq 0xff) { 
        $encoding = 'BigEndianUnicode' 
    } elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0xff -and $byte[1] -eq 0xfe) { 
         $encoding = 'Unicode' 
    } elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0 -and $byte[1] -eq 0 -and $byte[2] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[3] -eq 0xff) { 
        $encoding = 'UTF32' 
    } elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0x2b -and $byte[1] -eq 0x2f -and $byte[2] -eq 0x76) { 
        $encoding = 'UTF7'
    } else { 
        $encoding = 'ASCII' 
    }

$encoding
}
```

Seems like there's a bug here perhaps. Can someone else just verify if that 3 liner above returns Unicode for you? FWIW, this is a Windows 7 VM upgraded to PS5.

Comment: Set your `$OutputEncoding` preference variable to `[Text.UTF8Encoding]` or whatever you're aiming for.

Comment: Wow, is there really no way to do it on the $writer object directly, you have to use a preference variable? My understanding has always been to avoid preference variables when a more targeted approach is available. But maybe there is no other way?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx), there is a `.Encoding` property, but you need to use the proper constructor for the encoding that you want.  See the constructors in the same article.

Comment: @Gordon What makes you think `StreamReader` automatically detects the correct encoding?

Comment: @Mathias, well, the presence of a CurrentEncoding parameter, and the fact that the constructor references the file, so I ASSUMED it would use the encoding of the file. I take it I made an ass out of me? ;)
So what should this look like, to get the output file to match the encoding of the source file?

Answer (score 0):

`[System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]` is an object of type `[type]`.  You need an object that's an encoding type.  Try `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII` or `[System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII` or `[System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::new()`:

```
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII)
```

Comment: I think I must be doing something else wrong then, because [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII didn't work. See the OP for the revised code, showing how I am checking the encoding post Write. Maybe that's where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Gordon Have you read [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx) for `File.IO.StreamReader`?  The class *assumes* UTF-8 encoding if you don't supply one with the constructor overloads.  Also note that UTF-8 is a strict superset of ASCII

Comment: Yes, and I thought I was using a correct overload with
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
But my skills are pretty weak when it comes to .NET, so perhaps I am misunderstanding that part of the doco?

Comment: @Gordon That is a correct overload for the Writer.  However, you're "verifying" it by opening a Reader.  Well, the Reader *also* defaults to UTF-8 unless you tell it otherwise.  You can [ask StreamReader to auto-detect the encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but by default it assumes UTF-8.

Comment: @Gordon Try `[IO.StreamReader]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", $true)`.  However, you may still get UTF-8 because UTF-8 is a strict superset of traditional ASCII (i.e., not including the expanded ASCII characters 128-255).

Comment: Dang, I thought I was getting there. I tried
$writer = [IO.StreamWriter]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF16)
and
$test = [IO.StreamReader]::New("\\Mac\Support\Journal Tools\Aaron\stream.txt", $true)
and I'm still getting current encoding reported as UTF8. Ugh.